# What does this sha number in the git path of a gem in a Gemfile mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, gemfile

I see the following in a Gemfile below.

What does "5343434343424324b5:x-oauth-basic@github.com" mean? Is it a commit sha?  And then how would I find the branch it's on?  I've tried by looking at anything with tag 1.22.0

```
gem 'company-gem', git: 'https://5343434343424324b5:x-oauth-basic@github.com/CompanyName/company-gem.git', tag: '1.22.0', require: 'company-gem/core'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an OAuth url, [a feature introduced by GitHub in 2012](https://github.com/blog/1270-easier-builds-and-deployments-using-git-over-https-and-oauth).

`5343434343424324b5` is the OAuth token:

> If you're cloning inside a script and need to avoid the prompts, you
>   can add the token to the clone URL:
>
> git clone [https://*token*@github.com/owner/repo.git](https://_token_@github.com/owner/repo.git)

**Warning**: GitHub warns against embedding the token in the url for security reasons:

> Note: Tokens should be treated as passwords. Putting the token in the
>   clone URL will result in Git writing it to the .git/config file in
>   plain text

More information: https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/

Answer (score 0):

It's authentication information. In general, URLs can take the form "protocol://username@password:hostname/path". In this case, "5343434343424324b5" is the username part and "x-oauth-basic" is the password part, but it looks like the server side app is treating "5343434343424324b5" as some sort of OAuth token.